# How to delete a new item from the list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html-lists, domdocument

I'm new to JavaScript and I have made a list. You can add new items inn the list, you can delete the items from the list, also it has a little css for text decoration.

And I have a problem, I can't delete the new items from the list, I can only delete the old items from the list. If a add a new item, I can't delete it

This is the code:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var liEl = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("button");
var btnLength = btn.length;

function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var delBtn = document.createElement("button");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value + " "));
    delBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.appendChild(delBtn);
    btnLength++;
    btn[btnLength].addEventListener("click", clearItem);
    input.value = "";
}

function addListAfterClick() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(theEvent) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && theEvent.keyCode === 13) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function changeClass() {
    this.classList.toggle("done");
}

function clearItem() {
    this.parentNode.remove();
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);

eventChangeClass();

eventClearItem();

function eventChangeClass() {
    for (var i = 0; i < liEl.length; i++) {
    liEl[i].addEventListener("click", changeClass);
    }
}

function eventClearItem() {
    for (var i = 1; i < btnLength; i++) {
        btn[i].addEventListener("click", clearItem);
    }
}
```

```css
.done {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript + DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li>Jello <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li>Spinach <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li>Rice <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li>Birthday Cake <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li>Candles <button>Delete</button></li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
at createListElement (script.js:20)
at HTMLButtonElement.addListAfterClick (script.js:26)
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` is not a *live* collection of all `button`s. Quick fix might be to use `getElementsByTagName` instead, which *is* a live collection, but it would be even better to use event delegation instead.

Comment: `btn[btnLength]` will always be undefined even with a live collection as there is no element at *btnLength*.

Answer (score 1):

hey you placed some code in wrong place,
`btn = document.querySelectorAll("button");`
 `btn[btnlength].addEventListener("click", clearItem);`,
I changed this to `btn[btn.length].addEventListener("click", clearItem)`
you forget to take the new buttons, you only initialized `btn` on the page load, so each time you add new delete button, it is not added to the `btn` array. and you take `btnlength` only at the initial stage, so btn length varies. each time you need to reinit btn length. I have fixed and added a snippet. check that please.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var liEl = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("button");
var btnLength = btn.length;

function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var delBtn = document.createElement("button");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value + " "));
    delBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.appendChild(delBtn);
    btn = document.querySelectorAll("button");
    btnLength++;
   
    btn[btn.length -1].addEventListener("click", clearItem);
    input.value = "";
}

function addListAfterClick() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(theEvent) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && theEvent.keyCode === 13) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function changeClass() {
    this.classList.toggle("done");
}

function clearItem() {
    this.parentNode.remove();
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);

eventChangeClass();

eventClearItem();

function eventChangeClass() {
    for (var i = 0; i < liEl.length; i++) {
    liEl[i].addEventListener("click", changeClass);
    }
}

function eventClearItem() {
    for (var i = 1; i < btnLength; i++) {
        btn[i].addEventListener("click", clearItem);
    }
}
```

```css
.done {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript + DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li>Jello <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li>Spinach <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li>Rice <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li>Birthday Cake <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li>Candles <button>Delete</button></li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RobGm I added description

Comment: Thank you Akhil. Now I understand my mistake, I just have the index of the new list item, but btn[btnLength] do not exist.